# I cant solve this calculus gravitational problem.

Tags: mathematical-physics, education

Question: Given a ball of radius R of uniform density δ, and a point mass m of distance a from the center of the ball, assuming the gravitational constant is G, find the gravitational force of the ball exerted on the point mass.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYQNW.png)

I dont understand what is alpha and how alpha can tranform to R.

Comment: There isn't enough context in the attached image, but it seems that if you take a point $A$ outside the sphere of radius $R$, at distance $a$ from its centre $O$, and then take a tangent to the sphere, say at $P$, then $\alpha$ is the angle $OAP$.

Comment: If you're looking for a more general and useful formula with a relatively simpler proof (which can also be applied to this particular problem), try reading about Gauss's law for gravity (the proof is done using Gauss's theorem from vector calculus and Newton's law of gravity).

Comment: If you want us to answer questions about this particular calculation, then you need to show the entire calculation to us, not just one little bit that does not include the definitions of the things you are asking about.